# Subnet Device commication using consumer grade routers

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, nat, subnet

My ISP requires the use of their router that i am not able to view or configure. As such, i am using my own router (Asus AC5300) as an unfortunate second NAT. I now need to add a second router and would like to keep it logically separated via IP ranges. (192.168.1.X and 192.168.2.X) with a goal of having all or some of those devices communicate freely between the two ranges. I currently have the second router (another AC5300) set as an AP to the first. Now, this works, but it has quite a few devices on the .1 subnet (not over 254, but enough smart devices to make it irritating). I also tried to expand the subnet using a 255.255.255.248 mask. but since DHCP only works on the primary router i would have to statically assign each Router B device on Router A to the other range (not desirable). I have also had Router B in gateway mode (triple NAT) but device communication is only one-way.

I would like to set-up to the set-up shown in the sample layout below, but can't seem to get Router A devices to talk to Router B devices.
[Sample Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOii5.jpg)
Both routers connected to the ISP router in gateway mode using a simple switch since the ISP router has only one client port. But still retain open communication between devices.

I understand it may not be possible using the routers i have, but want to make sure their isn't something simple i am missing before shopping for better equipment.

Thoughts?

Comment: I looked at your picture. Replace the switch with a good router. Hook up the WAN side of this router to your ISP. Then go to the LAN side and make it a different subnet to your ISP. Make sure DHCP is ON.  Make sure it works and then hook your equipment to this router how you wish. The above isolates you from your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* technically possible given the routers are flexible enough – and as long as they have static "WAN" addresses. I don't really know if it is possible with your current router models.

First, the same "add a route" story: On each router, add a static route towards the opposite subnet, with the 'gateway' being the opposite router's IP address. Since the two routers are connected on WAN interfaces, use the routers' WAN IP addresses here.

- Router A: network 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.150.BB
- Router B: network 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.150.AA

Second, edit the routers' *firewall rules* to allow incoming packets from 192.168.1.0/24 to 192.168.2.0/24 and vice versa. Make this a high priority rule so that it overrides the default "block WAN stuff" rule that's likely there.

Third, if the two routers perform outbound NAT, see if you can make an exception for the local subnet – this is also made necessary by using the WAN interface to interconnect them. (It might be another rule under firewall settings.)

If NAT is on and you're not able to add NAT exceptions, it might still work, but won't be ideal.